# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, iis

We are using third party web service to send SMS. Web service does not require any certificate and if i enter service address in browser i get below output. As the output its confirmed that we do not need any certificate to call this service.

[image]

The service is working fine if i call it from my development machine using visual studio but from IIS im getting error

Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority.

Comment: Evidently IIS is trying to create an SSL connection - it's impossible to tell from what you've posted why that is.

Comment: Is there any way i can define configuration in web.config. I am using <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICorporateCBS1">
     <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in your code!

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`